# How to get started in information security with sales background?

Tags: professional-education, career

I am currently a Masters student looking to change career from sales to IT, specifically Information Security. What are some good resources about finding jobs? What skills should I focus on to get a security job?

Comment: do you have any knowledge on programming (if so to what level?, conning people and other social engineering?

Comment: Being really good at IT security means knowing almost everything in IT. Basic electronics, digital communication, hardware, programming, operating systems and understanding applications and their structure in general. IT Security sits on top of every other area in IT. Take a ground up approach, learn everything you can.

Comment: InfoSec is a wide topic. Do you have an idea what area you are interested in? Security+ would be a good place to get the most basic foundation, and then you narrow down from there. There are also tons of others asking similar questions here. Poke around.

Answer (score 2):

This was discussed recently here -> [How do I get started with security? (beginner)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15233/how-do-i-get-started-with-security-beginner/15248#15248). There are some excellent answers there.

Additionally, Robin Wood has recently done some research on this topic and I think you will find it useful. He presented it at BSides London recently and has posted his findings on his blog - http://www.digininja.org/projects/breaking_in_part_1.php.

I also did a blog post with a friend (@securityninja) on something similar a few months ago - http://www.securityninja.co.uk/application-security/random-thoughts-on-education-learning-from-markofu/ - which you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

How far are you in your masters program? Can you switch to info sec? Maybe check out Security+ Cert from [CompTIA](http://www.comptia.org/home.aspx), it's basic curriculum can give you a good intro so you can know if you really like the subject or not, and its valued throughout the industry.